# Model/Table Alias Not Working (INNER JOIN)

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, mariadb

## Problem Description

I have the `Users` table associated with the `Tests` table twice, once under the alias `Maintainers`. When I have the `Maintainers` `belongsTo` association defined there are no results returned. I need to figure out why this first query is not returning any results.

## Doesn't work

`` SELECT 
  Tests.id AS `Tests__id`, 
  Tests.title AS `Tests__title`, 
  Tests.slug AS `Tests__slug`, 
  Tests.description AS `Tests__description`, 
  Tests.user_id AS `Tests__user_id`, 
  Tests.maintainer_id AS `Tests__maintainer_id`, 
  Tests.test_question_count_total AS `Tests__test_question_count_total`, 
  Tests.test_question_count_mature AS `Tests__test_question_count_mature`, 
  Tests.test_session_count_total AS `Tests__test_session_count_total`, 
  Tests.test_session_count_mature AS `Tests__test_session_count_mature`, 
  Tests.photo AS `Tests__photo`, 
  Tests.photo_dir AS `Tests__photo_dir`, 
  Tests.photo_size AS `Tests__photo_size`, 
  Tests.view_count AS `Tests__view_count`, 
  Tests.published AS `Tests__published`, 
  Tests.mature AS `Tests__mature`, 
  Tests.flagged AS `Tests__flagged`, 
  Tests.deleted AS `Tests__deleted`, 
  Tests.created AS `Tests__created`, 
  Tests.modified AS `Tests__modified`, 
  Users.id AS `Users__id`, 
  Users.first_name AS `Users__first_name`, 
  Users.last_name AS `Users__last_name`, 
  Users.username AS `Users__username`, 
  Users.email AS `Users__email`, 
  Users.password AS `Users__password`, 
  Users.token AS `Users__token`, 
  Users.photo AS `Users__photo`, 
  Users.photo_dir AS `Users__photo_dir`, 
  Users.photo_size AS `Users__photo_size`, 
  Users.bio AS `Users__bio`, 
  Users.is_admin AS `Users__is_admin`, 
  Users.created AS `Users__created`, 
  Users.modified AS `Users__modified`, 
  Maintainers.id AS `Maintainers__id`, 
  Maintainers.first_name AS `Maintainers__first_name`, 
  Maintainers.last_name AS `Maintainers__last_name`, 
  Maintainers.username AS `Maintainers__username`, 
  Maintainers.email AS `Maintainers__email`, 
  Maintainers.password AS `Maintainers__password`, 
  Maintainers.token AS `Maintainers__token`, 
  Maintainers.photo AS `Maintainers__photo`, 
  Maintainers.photo_dir AS `Maintainers__photo_dir`, 
  Maintainers.photo_size AS `Maintainers__photo_size`, 
  Maintainers.bio AS `Maintainers__bio`, 
  Maintainers.is_admin AS `Maintainers__is_admin`, 
  Maintainers.created AS `Maintainers__created`, 
  Maintainers.modified AS `Maintainers__modified` 
FROM 
  tests Tests 
  INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Tests.user_id) 
  INNER JOIN users Maintainers ON Maintainers.id = (Tests.maintainer_id) 
WHERE 
  (
    Tests.slug = 'what-word-are-youquestion' 
    AND Tests.deleted IS NULL
  ) 
LIMIT 
  1 ``

## Works

`` SELECT 
  Tests.id AS `Tests__id`, 
  Tests.title AS `Tests__title`, 
  Tests.slug AS `Tests__slug`, 
  Tests.description AS `Tests__description`, 
  Tests.user_id AS `Tests__user_id`, 
  Tests.maintainer_id AS `Tests__maintainer_id`, 
  Tests.test_question_count_total AS `Tests__test_question_count_total`, 
  Tests.test_question_count_mature AS `Tests__test_question_count_mature`, 
  Tests.test_session_count_total AS `Tests__test_session_count_total`, 
  Tests.test_session_count_mature AS `Tests__test_session_count_mature`, 
  Tests.photo AS `Tests__photo`, 
  Tests.photo_dir AS `Tests__photo_dir`, 
  Tests.photo_size AS `Tests__photo_size`, 
  Tests.view_count AS `Tests__view_count`, 
  Tests.published AS `Tests__published`, 
  Tests.mature AS `Tests__mature`, 
  Tests.flagged AS `Tests__flagged`, 
  Tests.deleted AS `Tests__deleted`, 
  Tests.created AS `Tests__created`, 
  Tests.modified AS `Tests__modified`, 
  Users.id AS `Users__id`, 
  Users.first_name AS `Users__first_name`, 
  Users.last_name AS `Users__last_name`, 
  Users.username AS `Users__username`, 
  Users.email AS `Users__email`, 
  Users.password AS `Users__password`, 
  Users.token AS `Users__token`, 
  Users.photo AS `Users__photo`, 
  Users.photo_dir AS `Users__photo_dir`, 
  Users.photo_size AS `Users__photo_size`, 
  Users.bio AS `Users__bio`, 
  Users.is_admin AS `Users__is_admin`, 
  Users.created AS `Users__created`, 
  Users.modified AS `Users__modified`
FROM 
  tests Tests 
  INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Tests.user_id) 
WHERE 
  (
    Tests.slug = 'what-word-are-youquestion' 
    AND Tests.deleted IS NULL
  ) 
LIMIT 
  1 ``

EDIT: I was informed that an `INNER JOIN` expects data in both tables and that is potentially what was failing since in the `tests` table, `maintainer_id` was `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I am using the `CakePHP` framework. I ended up removing the `joinType` association from the association definition and let the framework decide the join type.

EDIT: I verified a hint someone told me (see OP edit), it was because `maintainer_id` in the particular record I was loading was set to `NULL` on a `LEFT JOIN`. A `LEFT JOIN` requires data to be in both tables. Once I set a `maintainer_id` to an existing record, everything worked. The better option, since `maintainer_id` is not always going to be populated is to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

### Doesn't work

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Maintainers', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'maintainer_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

### Works

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Maintainers', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'maintainer_id'
]);
```

## Resulting Query

```
SELECT 
  Tests.id AS `Tests__id`, 
  Tests.title AS `Tests__title`, 
  Tests.slug AS `Tests__slug`, 
  Tests.description AS `Tests__description`, 
  Tests.user_id AS `Tests__user_id`, 
  Tests.maintainer_id AS `Tests__maintainer_id`, 
  Tests.test_question_count_total AS `Tests__test_question_count_total`, 
  Tests.test_question_count_mature AS `Tests__test_question_count_mature`, 
  Tests.test_session_count_total AS `Tests__test_session_count_total`, 
  Tests.test_session_count_mature AS `Tests__test_session_count_mature`, 
  Tests.photo AS `Tests__photo`, 
  Tests.photo_dir AS `Tests__photo_dir`, 
  Tests.photo_size AS `Tests__photo_size`, 
  Tests.view_count AS `Tests__view_count`, 
  Tests.published AS `Tests__published`, 
  Tests.mature AS `Tests__mature`, 
  Tests.flagged AS `Tests__flagged`, 
  Tests.deleted AS `Tests__deleted`, 
  Tests.created AS `Tests__created`, 
  Tests.modified AS `Tests__modified`, 
  Users.id AS `Users__id`, 
  Users.first_name AS `Users__first_name`, 
  Users.last_name AS `Users__last_name`, 
  Users.username AS `Users__username`, 
  Users.email AS `Users__email`, 
  Users.password AS `Users__password`, 
  Users.token AS `Users__token`, 
  Users.photo AS `Users__photo`, 
  Users.photo_dir AS `Users__photo_dir`, 
  Users.photo_size AS `Users__photo_size`, 
  Users.bio AS `Users__bio`, 
  Users.is_admin AS `Users__is_admin`, 
  Users.created AS `Users__created`, 
  Users.modified AS `Users__modified`, 
  Maintainers.id AS `Maintainers__id`, 
  Maintainers.first_name AS `Maintainers__first_name`, 
  Maintainers.last_name AS `Maintainers__last_name`, 
  Maintainers.username AS `Maintainers__username`, 
  Maintainers.email AS `Maintainers__email`, 
  Maintainers.password AS `Maintainers__password`, 
  Maintainers.token AS `Maintainers__token`, 
  Maintainers.photo AS `Maintainers__photo`, 
  Maintainers.photo_dir AS `Maintainers__photo_dir`, 
  Maintainers.photo_size AS `Maintainers__photo_size`, 
  Maintainers.bio AS `Maintainers__bio`, 
  Maintainers.is_admin AS `Maintainers__is_admin`, 
  Maintainers.created AS `Maintainers__created`, 
  Maintainers.modified AS `Maintainers__modified` 
FROM 
  tests Tests 
  INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Tests.user_id) 
  LEFT JOIN users Maintainers ON Maintainers.id = (Tests.maintainer_id) 
WHERE 
  (
    Tests.slug = 'what-word-are-youquestion' 
    AND Tests.deleted IS NULL
  ) 
LIMIT 
  1
```